# How kafka 0.8 achieve message-level load balance?

Tags: load-balancing, partitioning, producer-consumer, apache-kafka

We know, in kafka 0.8, producer connect to broker directly, it without connecting to zookeeper. Than how it achieve zookeeper-based load balance on per-request basis?
Actually, when a topic be created, its partition will distributed in one or more brokers. When a message be sent, it will be delivered to a certain partition according to its key word. That is to say ,a certain must be sent to a fixed partition on a fixed broker. How the so called load balancing works?

Answer (score 1):

The load-balancing on the producer end is effectively determined by whether you want the broker to automatically partition based on a use-supplied key or have the broker handle which partition the message goes to automatically.

You don't *have* to specify the partition key if you don't want to, and as such you're load-balancing is limited to the number of partitions available to a given topic as opposed to the partition assigned to the key.

Answer (score 0):

kafka will need a Zookeepeer instance to connect to the broker. We can achieve load balancing by writing to partitons in a topic either by using a default partitioner or custome partitioner.